# compare block helper for handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

i working in code to compare values using block helper but the problem every time i run this code i get this error massage on my webpage view

> ```
> Error: Missing helper: "compare"
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/chessMult/regtest/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/helpers/helper-missing.js:19:13)
>     at Object.eval (eval at createFunctionContext (/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/chessMult/regtest/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js:254:23),
>     <anonymous>:8:91)
>     at main (/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/chessMult/regtest/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:175:32)
>     at ret (/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/chessMult/regtest/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:178:12)
>     at ret (/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/chessMult/regtest/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js:525:21)
>     at ExpressHandlebars._renderTemplate (/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/chessMult/regtest/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:247:12)
>     at ExpressHandlebars.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/chessMult/regtest/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:173:21)
> ```

**my index.hbs file**

```
{{#compare pageCount ">" 1 }}
  <ul class="pagination"><­/ul>
    {{#compare  currentPage ">" 1  }}

       <li><a href="/?page=1"> &laquo;</a></li>
    {{/compare}}

{{/compare}}
```

**my auth.js file**

```
res.render('index', {x:"1888", "personList": personList,data: data, pageSize: pageSize, pageCount: pageCount,currentPage: currentPage});
```

**my app.js file**

```
const exphbs     = require('express-handlebars');
const hbs = exphbs.create({
  // Specify helpers which are only registered on this instance.
  helpers: {
    foo: function () { return 'FOO!'; },
    extname: ".hbs",
    compare: function(lvalue, rvalue, options) {

      if (arguments.length < 3)
        throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' needs 2 parameters");

      var operator = options.hash.operator || "==";

      var operators = {
        '==':       function(l,r) { return l == r; },
        '===':      function(l,r) { return l === r; },
        '!=':       function(l,r) { return l != r; },
        '<':        function(l,r) { return l < r; },
        '>':        function(l,r) { return l > r; },
        '<=':       function(l,r) { return l <= r; },
        '>=':       function(l,r) { return l >= r; },
        'typeof':   function(l,r) { return typeof l == r; }
      }

      if (!operators[operator])
        throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' doesn't know the operator "+operator);

      var result = operators[operator](lvalue,rvalue);

      if( result ) {
        return options.fn(this);
      } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
      }

    }

  }
});


//For Handlebars
app.set('views', './app/views')
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

where's the wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small mistake at `app.js` file

```
const exphbs     = require('express-handlebars');
const hbs = exphbs.create({
//...
});

//For Handlebars
app.set('views', './app/views');
app.engine('.hbs', hbs.engine); // <===== Use `hbs.engine`
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```